# Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) is not defined at

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that this question have been asked some of stack-overflow users while ago.
I searched everywhere and couldn't to solve.

It is always getting following error when I click the button.

> Uncaught Reference Error: (function) is not defined at ..

Here is my code snippets

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){


        var display_table;
        var goto_bottom;

        display_table = function(){
            $("#search_button").click(function() {
            var values = [];
            $("input:checkbox[name=category_search]:checked").each(function(){
            //values.push($(this).next("a").text());
            values.push($(this).val());
            alert(values.join());
            });
        });    
        }

        goto_bottom = function(){
            $("#search_button").click(function() {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
            });​
        }

    });



        </script>
</head>
```

---

```
<body>
 <div style="position:fixed; top:95px; right:50px;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-fill" style="width:200px;" id="search_button" onclick="display_table() , goto_bottom()">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>search</button>
 </div>
</body>
```

Could anybody point out to me where the problem is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems I see with your code:

1. It looks like your code is using jQuery.  Make sure jQuery library is loaded. This line loads jQuery from Google APIS.  Just add it to your `<head>` tag.

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. You're mixing regular JavaScript and jQuery.
   You shouldn't be using onclick="display_table() , goto_bottom()" on your search button, and then have jQuery .click listening to the same "search_button".

$("#search_button").click is the jQuery click listener, which should check for checkbox values, and also animate the scroll.

You can remove onclick="display_table() , goto_bottom()"

The error you were getting, was JavaScript trying to find the display_table() function. But you don't have a that function defined.
You have a variable called display_table, that stores an unnamed function,  that's not the same as function display_table().

I have no idea what you're doing with your checkboxes, so I just added some checkboxes with your code cleaned up a bit:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_button").click(function () {
        var values = [];
        $("input:checkbox[name=category_search]:checked").each(function () {
            //values.push($(this).next("a").text());
            values.push($(this).val());
            
        });
        
        alert(values.join());
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="position:fixed; top:15px; right:50px;">
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="category_search" value="Category 1" />Category 1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="category_search" value="Category 2" />Category 2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="category_search" value="Category 3" />Category 3</li>
    </ul>
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-fill" style="width:200px;" id="search_button">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>search
    </button>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both; width:200px;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>

    <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. </p>

    <p>Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. </p>

    <p>Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. </p>

        <p>Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @casper: did this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Few closing stuffs missed here.. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var display_table;
    var goto_bottom;

    display_table = function(){
        $("#search_button").click(function() {
            $("#search_button").click(function() {
                var values = [];
                $("input:checkbox[name=category_search]:checked").each(function(){
                    values.push($(this).val());
                    alert(values.join());
                });    
            });
        });
    }

    goto_bottom = function(){
        $("#search_button").click(function() {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() },"slow");
        });​
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying with this much of code.You can simply try this if this is what you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#search_button").click(function() {
                var values = [];
                $("input:checkbox[name=category_search]:checked").each(function(){
                    values.push($(this).val());
                    alert(values.join());                       
                });  
               $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() },"slow");  
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="height:1800px;"><!-- height is added only to show scroll !-->
 <div style="position:fixed; top:95px; right:50px;">
 <input type="checkbox" name="category_search">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-fill" style="width:200px;" id="search_button" >
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>search</button>
 </div>
</body>
```